# How to compare dates in 2 DFs and count number of event occurred within 30 days

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

1. df1

|  | client_id | prediction_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100000201 | 2019-08-20 |
| 1 | 100000202 | 2020-02-27 |
| 2 | 100000204 | 2019-12-19 |

2. df2

| INC Number | Importance | Opened |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INC11 | minor | 2021-08-21 |
| INC22 | minor | 2020-03-17 |
| INC33 | major | 2019-12-12 |

The df1 is hundreds of thousands long, and df2 has only 20 rows.
I would like to count how many INC numbers occurred within **30 days** before clients prediction_date

No idea so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use broadcasting for compare columns converted to numpy arrays, subtract and compare if between 0 and 30 days, last `sum` for counter:

```
df1['prediction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['prediction_date'])
df2['Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Opened'])


arr = (df1['prediction_date'].to_numpy() - df2['Opened'].to_numpy()[:, None]) 

df1['count'] = np.sum((arr < pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')) & (arr > pd.Timedelta(0)), axis=0)
print (df1)
   client_id prediction_date  count
0  100000201      2019-08-20      0
1  100000202      2020-02-27      0
2  100000204      2019-12-19      1
```

Solution for count `Importance` values to new columns:

```
df1['prediction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['prediction_date'])
df2['Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Opened'])

days = pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')

arr = (df1['prediction_date'].to_numpy() - df2['Opened'].to_numpy()[:, None]) 
m = (arr < days) & (arr > pd.Timedelta(0))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(m, index=df2['Importance'], columns=df1.index)
print (df3)
                0      1      2
Importance                     
minor       False  False  False
minor       False  False  False
major       False  False   True

df1['count'] = df3.sum()
print (df1)
   client_id prediction_date  count
0  100000201      2019-08-20      0
1  100000202      2020-02-27      0
2  100000204      2019-12-19      1

df1 = df1.join(df3.sum(level=0).T)
print (df1)
   client_id prediction_date  count  minor  major
0  100000201      2019-08-20      0      0      0
1  100000202      2020-02-27      0      0      0
2  100000204      2019-12-19      1      0      1
```

Comment: thank you, that is what I was looking for

Comment: Actually, one more question - how to group count by df2['Importance'] ?

Answer (score 0):

If `df1` is huge and `df2` is very small, then looping over the smaller one is faster and memory friendly.

```py
df1.prediction_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.prediction_date)
df2.Opened = pd.to_datetime(df2.Opened)

df1["INC_count"] = 0
for d in df2.Opened:
    df1.INC_count = df1.INC_count + (
        (d >= df1.prediction_date - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')) &
        (d <= df1.prediction_date)).astype(int)
df1
```

[image]

Another option I would consider is to use [sqldf](https://pypi.org/project/sqldf/) library and merge the two with the inequality condition.